# ActionScript 3.0 UncaughtErrorEvent not working properly

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, exception

I don't really understand UncaughtErrorEvent and can't get it working for my Air 2.6 application. If I step through the code with the debugger, I get very strange results.

This is the code:

```
 public class Main extends Sprite{
      public function Main(){
           loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);          
                     // ...
           }
           ...
      private function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
      {
           var error:Error = e.error;
           Logger.log("Uncaught Error - Type: " + e.type + " - Message: " + error.message, "session");
      }
 }
```

I'm setting a breakpoint on the line `var error:Error = e.error;` and start the application
at one point, an exception occurs and the debugger properly breaks on the specific line.

Now comes the odd part.

When I click on "step over (F6)" I would expect the application to jump to the next line "Logger.log(..." - but instead, the Console will display the exception that was thrown

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

and the application goes just back running. The line "Logger.log(..." is never executed
how is this even possible? How can it be that the debugger breaks on `var error:Error = e.error` but the next line is not executed?

Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AS3 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html) reads

> When content is running in a debugger
>   version of the runtime, such as the
>   debugger version of Flash Player or
>   the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL), an
>   uncaught error dialog appears when an
>   uncaught error happens. For those
>   runtime versions, the error dialog
>   appears even when a listener is
>   registered for the uncaughtError
>   event. To prevent the dialog from
>   appearing in that situation, call the
>   UncaughtErrorEvent object's
>   preventDefault() method.

Comment: And by the way, `e.error` can be either an `Error` or an `ErrorEvent`.